# Copy consutrctor w/ multiple pointers

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am trying to create a copy constructor for a class with pointer variables. Something is going wrong with the copy construction though, as I segfault when I try to access pointers in my new object...

```
/* Copy Constructor */ 
Solver::Solver(const

 Solver &obj)
    {
    // Pointers to use in modified-Midpoint method.
    double *m_yTemp1 = new double[CONST_numVariables];
    double *m_yTemp2 = new double[CONST_numVariables];
    double *m_dTemp  = new double[CONST_numVariables];

    // Triple pointer to store tableau of data for extrapolation.
    double ***m_extrapTableau = new double**[CONST_maxDiv];
    *m_extrapTableau          = *obj.m_extrapTableau;
    for(int i=0; i<CONST_maxDiv; i++)
    {
        m_extrapTableau[i]  = new double*[i+1];
        *m_extrapTableau[i] = *obj.m_extrapTableau[i];
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            m_extrapTableau[i][j]  = new double[CONST_numVariables];
            *m_extrapTableau[i][j] = *obj.m_extrapTableau[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Pointer of step sizes for extrapolation of modified-Midpoint.
    double *CONST_extrap = new double[CONST_maxDiv];
    for(int i=0; i<CONST_maxDiv; i++)
    {
        CONST_extrap[i] = 2.*(i+1.);
    }

    // Change pointer of new object from already used memory to newly allocated. 
    *m_yTemp1     = *obj.m_yTemp1;
    *m_yTemp2     = *obj.m_yTemp2;
    *m_dTemp      = *obj.m_dTemp;
    *CONST_extrap = *obj.CONST_extrap;
}
```

My initial questions are:

1. If I have other non-pointer variables in the class, are they automatically copied or do I need to specify them as well?
2. How do I deal with passing the address of double or triple pointers? I think I may be doing this wrong.
3. If CONST_numVariables and CONST_maxDiv are constants set in the class, can they be used in this copy constructor, assuming that they have been set when I copy an object?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, and forget about all this three-star nonsense. Besides, I'm not sure what you wanted to do with stuff like `*m_extrapTableau = *obj.m_extrapTableau;`, but what it does is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: You can use a debugger to see what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: "If I have other non-pointer variables in the class, are they automatically copied or do I need to specify them as well?" If you provide your own copy constructor, nothing is copied automatically.

Comment: Just fyi, it is not apparent at all your *intent* with `*m_yTemp1 = *obj.m_yTemp1;` was to copy just the **first** element of the array, but that is *exactly* what is happening. Nor is i clear why every single one of these are **local** automatic variables. I.e. you're declaring *all* of these local to your copy-ctor, thereby hiding your actual member variables so they (the *real* members) are utterly unchanged and indeterminate when this is finished (thus your seg-faults). The ensuing memory leaks are a bonus.

Comment: @T.C. - noted on the vector, probably easier. So what exactly does *m_extrapTableau = *obj.m_extrapTableau; do? I thought it assigned the address in memory of obj.m_extrapTableau to that of m_extrapTableau?

Comment: To avoid exception-unsafety and other bugs, no class should have more that one owned raw pointer. In other words, the only classes that should have owned pointers are the implementations of containers and smart pointers. The result of this is that any higher-level classes usually don't need a copy-ctor at all, since the copy-ctor of all their elements DTRT.

Comment: In case you were wondering what people were talking about, [see it live here](http://ideone.com/HtkckC).

Comment: @WhozCraig OT for this post, but how does `2.*(i+1.);` compile - shouldn't the maximal munch rule say that `.*` is the pointer-to-member operator?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Because the munching started on the deuce; not the dot. As such we went from `int` to `float` to mulop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your segfault is here:

```
double ***m_extrapTableau = new double**[CONST_maxDiv];  // (1)
*m_extrapTableau          = *obj.m_extrapTableau;        // (2)
```

In (1) you DECLARE a variable `m_extrapTableau` LOCAL to your constructor.
But in (2) I can see that you have a class membber with the same name.  So the local `m_extrapTableau` of your constructor will be properly intialised.  But it hides the class member that will remain uninitialized for subsequent uses.

About your remaining questions:

1) if you implement a copy constructor, you have to take care of copying everything you need.

2) passing adress of double or tripple pointers requires you to iterate through each level initializing the pointers correctly before using any element of your table. You should consider using vectors of vectors or vectors of vectors of vectors.  These a much more easy to initialise, copy, etc...

3) if they are const and you didn't initialize them to another value with a brace initializer they should be usable as such.

Comment: As long as we're fixing a brittle implementation done with raw pointers, may as well point out the fact the `i<=j` condition in the table initialization inner-loop is wrong, and will invoke undefined behavior on the top-end when used in the ensuing dereferences. Also, *all* of the `*ptr = *obj.ptr` style assignments (such as the one in this answer), though not syntactically wrong, are only copying the *first* element of the sequence. Either a `std::copy` or `std::memcpy` is likely warranted.

Comment: @WhozCraig I opted for the swap to vectors and it took less time to get it running successfully than it did to post on here looking for help. Clearly the copy constructor of raw pointers and multiple levels of them is above my coding experience. When you say wrong on the i<=j, how so? If I wanted a essentially a growing table of pointers, e.g. row of size 2, row of size 3, ..., how would I do that differently?

Comment: @BenSouthworth it was actually `j<=i` and you're right. I utterly was answering a different question in my head. no worries it should be ok (the indexing part, the vector-copying part stands).